# Installing debian package through Synaptic

Tags: synaptic

I want to install a .deb file. After going through various questions, I came across these three options: dpkg, GDebi and Ubuntu Software Center. However, I want to install the. Deb file via Synaptic Package Manager only. Is there any method by which I can install. Deb file as well as all it's dependencies via Synaptic Package Manager?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you must use Synaptic? Anything installed on your system will still show in Synaptic no matter what method of installation was used.

Comment: Yes, he wants dependencies to be installed (USC does that; dpkg and gdebit do not). Is there a reason why not using USC (this IS basically the same as using synaptic but with a frontend)

Comment: Well that's a personal opinion of not using USC!I won't debate over USC vs Synaptic but one thing that goes against USC(atleast in my case) is that I cann't change the proxy settings of my network,which Synaptic allows me to do.

Comment: Like anyone else: if you want that software either use USC or you need to install all dependencies yourself when using dpkg. Nothing else in between :+

Comment: I don't know guys. I use gdebi-gtk all the time and it installs dependencies for me. The only time it doesn't is if the necessary dependency is not in the repos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well actually you **can't** install .deb files through Synaptic.

Comment: Is there any reference to your statement,where I can read about it more?

Comment: Here you go: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=327329 and http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=47379

Comment: my reference: man apt-get

Answer (score -2):

You have to install it by command-line:

> sudo dpkg -i filename.deb

Command-line is faster and easier as you can know the problem (if there is any) by the debugging information it provides.

Comment: dpkg does not resolve dependencies,as was mentioned in earlier comments.